# Nested route with dinamically generated link with reach router in Gatsby

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hyperlink, gatsby, reach-router

I have a page generated By gatsby CreatePage with a template where I setup a Router using reach/router.

In order to show the problem, below there is a simpilfied version of the code.
The router has two nested routes:

MyTemplate.js

```
 ...   
    <Router basepath={`/${slug}`}>
      <CategoryBar path= "/"> 
        <PostSelector path= "works" category= {category}>   
          <Post path= "test" category={category}></Post>
        </PostSelector>
      </CategoryBar>
    </Router>
```

In `<PostSelector>` component links are dinamically generated  trough a .map method.

**Problem:** It looks like {props.children} is not passed dowm; the links are generated and rendered, but clicking them  the `<Post>` component is not rendered.

Here the code of `<PostSelector>`

PostSelector.js

```
...
const PostSelector =( {category}, props) => { 
        return(   
            category.edges.map((post, i) => (
                <div key={i}>
                    <ul>
                    <Link to="test">{post.node.title}</Link> 
                    </ul>
                {props.children}
                </div>
                
            ))
        )
}
```

If i replace the dinamically generated links with hard coded link it works as expected rendering `<Post>` as child of `<PostSelector>`

Any help would be really appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
const PostSelector =( {category, children}) => { 
        return(   
            category.edges.map((post, i) => (
                <div key={i}>
                    <ul>
                    <Link to="test">{post.node.title}</Link> 
                    </ul>
                {children}
                </div>
                
            ))
        )
}
```